# C# Mongo BsonSerializer.Deserialize Ignore elements that do not exist

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is there a flat that will tell the C# Mongo BsonSerializer to ignore elements that do not exist in the poco class

Example collection

```
Animal {"Type" : "Cat", "Skill" : "Jump"}
Animal {"Type" : "Dog", "Skill" : "Bark", "Owner" : "Jimmy"}
```

If the cat C# class only has

```
public string Type {get;set;}
public string Skill {get;set;}
```

When I attempt to execute the following

```
 var test = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Animal>(result);
```

The first item will work fine, the second one will throw an exception that Owner does not exist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use **[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]** attribute on Cat class.
From attribute summary:

> Specifies whether extra elements should be ignored when this class is
>   deserialized.

Comment: Can I set that definition globally instead as class attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use Convention to do it for all types at once

```cs
var conventionPack = new ConventionPack { new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true) };
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreExtraElements", conventionPack, _ => true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can  deserialize as an object, and use dynamic to receive it.

`dynamic test = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(result);`

Comment: I was thinking that, but was afraid that could cause a performance hit